# gst_parse_launch there is no proper conversion function from string to gchar

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch, gst-launch-1.0

I have a simple code with c++ using gstreamer to read rtsp video.
I'm new to gstreamer, I couldn't concatenate gst_parse_launch() with a URL_RTSP variable for my rtsp links.

here is no variable URL_RTSP, that works:

```
  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch("rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=rtsp://user:pass@protocol:port/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0 latency=300 ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

with the variable URL_RTSP, doesn't work:

```
  /*Url Cams*/
  std::string URL_RTSP = "rtsp://user:pass@protocol:port/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0";

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch("rtspsrc protocols=tcp location="+ URL_RTSP + " latency=300 ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

Error when I try to use with variable, gst_parse_launch() get the error:

```
there is no proper conversion function from "std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" to "const gchar *"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gst_parse_launch`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstparse.html?gi-language=c#gst_parse_launch) takes a `const gchar*` as the first argument:

```cpp
GstElement* gst_parse_launch (const gchar* pipeline_description, GError** error)
```

But, what you provide,

```cpp
"rtspsrc protocols=tcp location="+ URL_RTSP + 
" latency=300 ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink"
```

results in a `std::string`. I suggest creating the `std::string` first, then use the `c_str()` member function to pass it a `const char*`.

```cpp
std::string tmp =
    "rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=" + URL_RTSP +
    " latency=300 ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink";

pipeline = gst_parse_launch(tmp.c_str(), nullptr);
```